# Fetch XML Content into HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, html

I am a newbie to HTML/JS, so I am hoping you experts can help me out here with a small question. I have html5 music player with playlist, contents of which are currently mentioned within the index.html file as follows:

```
<div id="divListing">
    <ol id="olContents">
<li rel="http://www.abc.mp3"><strong>Song1</strong><a target="_blank" href=" ">Buy Song</a><em>Artist1</em></li>
<li rel="http://www.abcd.mp3"><strong>Song2</strong><a target="_blank" href=" ">Buy Song< /a><em>Artist2</em></li>
<li rel="http://www.abcde.mp3"><strong>Song3</strong><a target="_blank" href=" ">Buy Song</a><em>Artist1</em></li>
<li rel="http://www.abcdef.mp3"><strong>Song4</strong><a target="_blank" href=" ">Buy Song</a><em>Artist2</em></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

My goal is to get `<li>` items from a XML file so that I don't have to keep updating the html file every time but instead if I change the strings on my external(dropbox like) source.XML file being maintained in the same syntax as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<data>               
<li rel="http://www.abc.mp3"><strong>Song1</strong><a target="_blank" href=" ">Buy Song</a><em>Artist1</em></li>
<li rel="http://www.abcd.mp3"><strong>Song2</strong><a target="_blank" href=" ">Buy Song</a><em>Artist2</em></li>
<li rel="http://www.abcde.mp3"><strong>Song3</strong><a target="_blank" href=" ">Buy Song</a><em>Artist1</em></li>
<li rel="http://www.abcdef.mp3"><strong>Song4</strong><a target="_blank" href=" ">Buy Song</a><em>Artist2</em></li>

</data>
```

I am not sure how to associate or call the XML file so that html can read them as if they were being called directly in html.

Any code help you can share will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without spelling out all the code, I'd use AJAX to make a request for the XML file. Then once you receive that data, you can use javascript/jQuery to insert that HTML into your list.

Comment: I have jquery.js already instantiated in my html. But, I'm afraid I'm not there yet in understanding the syntax how I modify jquery to insert html or use AJAx. Syntax would be indeed helpful at this stage. Or even a reference anywhere on the web with a working example is what will be truly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to get your solution

1. Create a Web Service/ Web Api which will return Songs XML from server.
2. Call that webservice using jQuery Ajax
3. Read response and create `li` HTML elements dynamically as per XML response.

Comment: Or for (3), just use the XML directly in the HTML and use CSS to style it into a list. There (may) be no reason to change them to HTML tags, you can write css against the pure XML in the browser Like:
myXMLtag { display:list-item; font-weight: bold; ...}